# SwiftUI text placeholder in front of textField makes textField un-clickable

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am creating a custom text field with a custom placeholder in front of it, using the following method.

```
struct textView: View {
    @State var fieldTest: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if fieldTest == "" {
                Text("Placeholder")
            }
            
            TextField("", text: $fieldTest)
        }
    }
}
```

The only problem is that while running the app, if I press on the textfield's placeholder in order to edit the textfield, the field won't activate. I believe that this is caused from the Text() getting the tap event and not forwarding it to the text field. How can I solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with `TextField("Placeholder", text: $fieldTest)`? Btw, your code works fine with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

Comment: I've dropped your exact code into a functioning Xcode 12 project targeting iOS 14 and I can also confirm that it works fine.